# delete a specific line that includes a key sequence of numbers python

Tags: python, data-files

I have the below datafile and i want to delete the entire line that contains the "30" number in the first column. This number has always this position.

What i have thought is to read the file and create a list with this first column
and do a check if this number "30" exist on every item on the list and then delete the entire line given the index.

However i am not sure how to proceed.

Please let me know your thoughts .

[Datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbwo.png)

Here is what i have tried up to this point:

```
  f = open("file.txt","r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f = open("file.txt","w")

    for line in lines:
      if line!="30"+"\n": 
        f.write(line)

    f.close()
```

Comment: `if '30' not in line[4:6]: ` this will let you write only the lines which don't have 30 in that exact spot. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("file.txt", "w")

for line in lines:
    if '30' not in line[4:6]:
        f.write(line)

f.close()
```

Try this

Comment: Wouldn't `line[4:6] != '30'` make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use pandas, you could do it in three lines:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in file
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

# Remove rows where first column contains '30'
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('30')]

# Save the result
df.to_csv("cleaned.txt", sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

This approach can easily be extended to perform other types of filtering or manipulating your data.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is use the regular expressions that captures 30 in the beginning is this:

```
import re
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("file.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    if re.search(r'^\d*30',line):
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Hope it works well.